# I want to eliminate the repetitive appearance of the table I drew in my program. Is there a way that I can put this in a separate function?

Tags: c, function

I'm creating a program that asks for coordinates from the user and then it marks that coordinate with a capital O on the table. I've already made the program mark the letter O on cells A1-A3 if ever they are inputted by the user. But the program I made is going to be very long because I repeatedly enter the table within each condition. Is there a way that I can separate the table and put it in a function?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char first [3], second [3], third [3];
    char A1 = ' ', A2 = ' ', A3 = ' ';
    char B1 = ' ', B2 = ' ', B3 = ' ';
    char C1 = ' ', C2 = ' ', C3 = ' ';

    static const char a1[] = "a1";
    static const char a2[] = "a2";
    static const char a3[] = "a3";
    static const char b1[] = "b1";
    static const char b2[] = "b2";
    static const char b3[] = "b3";
    static const char c1[] = "c1";
    static const char c2[] = "c2";
    static const char c3[] = "c3";

    printf("   1   2   3");
    printf("\n +---+---+---+");
    printf("\nA| %c | %c | %c |", A1, A2, A3);
    printf("\n +---+---+---+");
    printf("\nB| %c | %c | %c |", B1, B2, B3);
    printf("\n +---+---+---+");
    printf("\nC| %c | %c | %c |", C1, C2, C3);
    printf("\n +---+---+---+");

    printf("\n\nCoordinates should be entered in this format, lower cap for columns followed by row number.\nExample: a1, b2, c3, etc.");
    printf("\n\nPlease enter 1st coordinate: ");
    scanf("%3s", &first);

    if (!strcmp(first,a1)){
    A1 = 'O';
    system("cls");
    printf("   1   2   3");
    printf("\n +---+---+---+");
    printf("\nA| %c | %c | %c |", A1, A2, A3);
    printf("\n +---+---+---+");
    printf("\nB| %c | %c | %c |", B1, B2, B3);
    printf("\n +---+---+---+");
    printf("\nC| %c | %c | %c |", C1, C2, C3);
    printf("\n +---+---+---+");
    }

    if (!strcmp(first,a2)){
    A2 = 'O';
    system("cls");
    printf("   1   2   3");
    printf("\n +---+---+---+");
    printf("\nA| %c | %c | %c |", A1, A2, A3);
    printf("\n +---+---+---+");
    printf("\nB| %c | %c | %c |", B1, B2, B3);
    printf("\n +---+---+---+");
    printf("\nC| %c | %c | %c |", C1, C2, C3);
    printf("\n +---+---+---+");
    }

    if (!strcmp(first,a3)){
    A3 = 'O';
    system("cls");
    printf("   1   2   3");
    printf("\n +---+---+---+");
    printf("\nA| %c | %c | %c |", A1, A2, A3);
    printf("\n +---+---+---+");
    printf("\nB| %c | %c | %c |", B1, B2, B3);
    printf("\n +---+---+---+");
    printf("\nC| %c | %c | %c |", C1, C2, C3);
    printf("\n +---+---+---+");
    }

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The fact that your `printf` army is exactly the same at the tail of each `if` should give you a hint...

Comment: Write a function? Make a `printTable()` function that you pass the appropriate data into, and call it after you've evaluated the if.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add function `printTable`.

```
void printTable(char A1, char A2, char A3,
                char B1, char B2, char B3,
                char C1, char C2, char C3)
{
    system("cls");
    printf("   1   2   3");
    printf("\n +---+---+---+");
    printf("\nA| %c | %c | %c |", A1, A2, A3);
    printf("\n +---+---+---+");
    printf("\nB| %c | %c | %c |", B1, B2, B3);
    printf("\n +---+---+---+");
    printf("\nC| %c | %c | %c |", C1, C2, C3);
    printf("\n +---+---+---+");
}
```

Call the function from `main` at appropriate places.

```
int main(){
    char first [3], second [3], third [3];
    char A1 = ' ', A2 = ' ', A3 = ' ';
    char B1 = ' ', B2 = ' ', B3 = ' ';
    char C1 = ' ', C2 = ' ', C3 = ' ';

    static const char a1[] = "a1";
    static const char a2[] = "a2";
    static const char a3[] = "a3";
    static const char b1[] = "b1";
    static const char b2[] = "b2";
    static const char b3[] = "b3";
    static const char c1[] = "c1";
    static const char c2[] = "c2";
    static const char c3[] = "c3";

    printTable(A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3, C1, C2, C3);

    printf("\n\nCoordinates should be entered in this format, lower cap for columns followed by row number.\nExample: a1, b2, c3, etc.");
    printf("\n\nPlease enter 1st coordinate: ");
    scanf("%3s", &first);

    if (!strcmp(first,a1)){
    A1 = 'O';
    printTable(A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3, C1, C2, C3);
    }

    if (!strcmp(first,a2)){
    A2 = 'O';
    printTable(A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3, C1, C2, C3);
    }

    if (!strcmp(first,a3)){
    A3 = 'O';
    printTable(A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3, C1, C2, C3);
    }

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

**Further Simplification**

Create an array of characters to store the data and use the array instead of having so many variables.

```
void printTable(char data[][3])
{
   char* A = data[0];
   char* B = data[1];
   char* C = data[2];

    system("cls");
    printf("   1   2   3");
    printf("\n +---+---+---+");
    printf("\nA| %c | %c | %c |", A[0], A[1], A[2]);
    printf("\n +---+---+---+");
    printf("\nB| %c | %c | %c |", B[0], B[1], B[2]);
    printf("\n +---+---+---+");
    printf("\nC| %c | %c | %c |", C[0], C[1], C[2]);
    printf("\n +---+---+---+");
}

int main(){
    char first [3], second [3], third [3];
    char data[][3] = {' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '};

    static const char a1[] = "a1";
    static const char a2[] = "a2";
    static const char a3[] = "a3";
    static const char b1[] = "b1";
    static const char b2[] = "b2";
    static const char b3[] = "b3";
    static const char c1[] = "c1";
    static const char c2[] = "c2";
    static const char c3[] = "c3";

    printTable(data);

    printf("\n\nCoordinates should be entered in this format, lower cap for columns followed by row number.\nExample: a1, b2, c3, etc.");
    printf("\n\nPlease enter 1st coordinate: ");
    scanf("%3s", &first);

    if (!strcmp(first,a1)){
    data[0][0] = 'O';
    printTable(data);
    }

    if (!strcmp(first,a2)){
    data[0][1] = 'O';
    printTable(data);
    }

    if (!strcmp(first,a3)){
    data[0][2] = 'O';
    printTable(data);
    }

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could simplify this further by putting the `printTable(data)` just once after the `if` statements

Answer (score 0):

Main body:

```
char[3][3] arr = ' '; //initialise array to ' '
if(input == a1) //find correct cell
arr[0][0] = 'O'; // change value
//check others
printTable(arr);
```

And for the method:

```
void printTable(char[][] arr)
{
printf("   1   2   3");
printf("\n +---+---+---+");
printf("\nA| %c | %c | %c |", arr[0][0], arr[1][0], arr[2][0]);
printf("\n +---+---+---+");
printf("\nB| %c | %c | %c |", arr[0][1], arr[1][1], arr[2][1]);
printf("\n +---+---+---+");
printf("\nC| %c | %c | %c |", arr[0][2], arr[1][2], arr[2][2]);
printf("\n +---+---+---+");
}
```

Bear in mind with this that I've not run this through a compiler, and I'm pretty sure that that's not how you handle arrays, but it's a rough idea for a start, if a mite inefficient.